# checkout page is being redirected to 404 error instead of thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, smtp, content-management-system, cartflows

I have a WordPress website with woo commerce functionality. I have used cartflows for customizing the checkout page and thank you page. now the problems are:

1. after payment is successful, it redirects customers to 404 page rather than thank you page.
2. order status doesn't update as completed even after payment is successful.
3. emails for cash on delivery and bank transfers are being received two times.

can someone please assist me how can I resolve these errors???

Answer (score 0):

Mb you've not selected which page is the Success page in WooCommerce settings?
Or this page is not created in Page.

Check these points first.

Comment: All pages are created, and they are perfectly working with direct bank transfer and cash on delivery, But they give 404 redirection when user purchase with debit/credit card. after payment gets successful it redirects them on 404 page.